# How to stop the same text appearing in the new paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
const texts = document.querySelector(".texts");

window.SpeechRecognition =
  window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

const recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition();
recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.continuous = true;

let p = document.createElement("p");

recognition.addEventListener("result", (e) => {

  const text = Array.from(e.results)
    .map((result) => result[0])
    .map((result) => result.transcript)
    .join("");

  p.innerText = text;
  texts.appendChild(p)

  if (e.results[0].isFinal) {
    if (text.includes("hello")) {
      p = document.createElement("p");
      p.classList.add("replay");
      p.innerText = "Hi";
      texts.appendChild(p);
    }

    p = document.createElement("p");
  } 

  console.log(e);
});

recognition.addEventListener("end", () => {
  recognition.start();
});

recognition.start();
```

Whenever I say "hello" *at the beginning, "hello" will always appear on my next paragraph.

How to fix this?

I'm hoping that you could solve this without adding third-party packages. I want logic. If you need so please write a description.

Comment: file:///Users/megawatykamir/Desktop/Screenshot%202023-08-06%20at%2006.11.34.png, this is the image, i hope you can open it.

Comment: Of course we cannot open that.  Its a file on YOUR computer.  You need to put that on an web server somewhere.